# FPDF Including an image in fancytable

Tags: image, fpdf

I'm trying to insert an image in a FPDF fancytable.
I tried to put inside the fancytable function the following :

$this->Cell($w[1],6,$pdf->Image('lettre.jpg',0,0,20,0),'LRB',0,'C',$fill);

but I have (of course) the following error message :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pdf in /MyScript.php on line 143
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: pdf in /MyScript.php on line 143
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Image() on
>   null in /MyScript.php:143
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 /MyScript.php(172): PDF->FancyTable(Array, Array)
>
> 1 {main}   thrown in /MyScript.php on line 143

I understand that I call the pdf function inside the fancytable function (part of the pdf function), so do I have a solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, the answer was in the question : just replaced $pdf by $this and it fixed my problem..

I let the question here just in case somebody have the same error one day ^^

Comment: And `Image()` returns nothing so it makes no sense to embed the call inside `Cell()`.